# Gradle: How do I configure a plugin extension (eg. checkstyle {...}) for all subprojects?

Tags: java, gradle

I have the following in my root `build.gradle` file.

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

    checkstyle {
        maxWarnings = 0
    }
}
```

But it seems IntelliJ only recognizes the `checkstyle` extension block if I put the above in a `allprojects` block. The IDE simply greys out the `checkstyle` keyword and underlines it with a squiggly line. See the image for reference.

[image: checkstyle config not recognized]

When put under the `allprojects` block, it works fine:

[image]

Can someone explain to me what is happening here? If this is just an IDE thing, would love to have some insight into why this might be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it's just an IDE thing and happens because in case you are using the `allproject` configuration, then your current project is getting a `checkstyle` plugin applied too, like all it's child projects, and IDE can find a `checkstyle` configuration closure.

Opposite, if you are using the `subproject`, your current project configuration doesn't have a `checkstyle` plugin apllied and IDE can't see a closure to configure it in the scope of this project.

Comment: But I do feel like the IDE should be able to handle this case gracefully.